# Can I specify a working dir when launching process with std::system?

Tags: c++, process

I want to launch an executable given it's full path:

`std::system("C:/binary.exe")`

Is there any way to specify a working directory in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a portable way to achieve what you want, at least it is not mandated by the C++ standard from what I can tell. Generally speaking, if you need more functionality than `system()` provides, you should look elsewhere. On Linux and Unix systems, this would be the [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) and [`exec(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) functions. On Windows [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx).

Untested code for a Linux way to achieve this would be:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main()
{
    const pid_t pid( fork() );
    if ( !pid ) {
        // child process
        if ( chdir("/tmp") ) {
            perror( "chdir" );
        }
        execl( "/binary", "binary", (char*)0 );
        perror( "execl(\"/binary\")" );
        _exit( 1 );
    }
}
```